# Поиск в GridView

Tags: php, sql, yii2, gridview

При связке новостей с категориями перестал в GridView работать поиск по id и title.
Выдаёт ошибку:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
>   where clause is ambiguous The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM `123_news` LEFT JOIN `123_news_category` ON
>   `123_news`.`category` = `123_news_category`.`id` WHERE `id`='2'

В модели:

```
public function getNewsCategory()
{
    return News::hasOne(NewsCategory::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
}
```

В поиске:

```
$query->joinWith('newsCategory');
```

В GridView:

```
'category' => [
    'attribute' => 'category',
        'value' => function($model){ return $model->newsCategory['title']; },
        'filter' => NewsCategory::allNewsCategory(),
],
```

Но поиск по категориям, просмотрам и статусу работает.

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось намного проще.
В модель:

```
public function getNewsCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(NewsCategory::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
}

public function getNewsCategoryTitle()
{
    return $this->newsCategory->title;
}
```

В поиск:

```
public $newsCategoryTitle;
```

В GridView:

```
    'category' => [
        'attribute' => 'category',
        'value' => 'newsCategoryTitle',
        'filter' => NewsCategory::allNewsCategory(),
    ],
```